# ERROR [ExceptionHandler] No repository for "Product" was found. Nest.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, entity

I am trying to register and migrate a new entity (Nest.js) but it fails with the following error text:

```
ERROR [ExceptionHandler] No repository for "Product" was found. Looks like this entity is not registered in the current "default" connection?
```

product.entity.ts

```
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";


@Entity()
export class Product {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  image: string;
}
```

product.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ProductController } from './product.controller';
import { TypeOrmModule } from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import { Product } from "./product.entity";

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Product])
  ],
  controllers: [ProductController]
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [auto load entities](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-entities) feature to circumvent that.
(like I said on discord)